# How can I patch an image field in a reactive form in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, file-upload, angular-reactive-forms, patch

I'm struggling with this issue. I have a form where I create an item, and this item can have a thumbnail. In order to upload the image I used the `ngx-mat-file-input` library. And I create the upload as follows:

`component.html`:

```html
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <ngx-mat-file-input #photo  formControlName="photo" placeholder="Image" (change)="onAddImage($event)"></ngx-mat-file-input>
                            <button mat-icon-button matSuffix *ngIf="!photo.empty" (click)="photo.clear($event); ">
                                <mat-icon matSuffix>clear</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                            <mat-icon matSuffix  *ngIf="photo.empty">photography</mat-icon>

                            <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('photo', 'maxContentSize')">
                                The total size must not exceed {{itemForm.get('photo')?.getError('maxContentSize').maxSize | byteFormat}} ({{itemForm.get('photo')?.getError('maxContentSize').actualSize
                            | byteFormat}}).
                            </mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <div *ngIf="!photo.empty" style="float: left; margin: 5px">
                            <img [src]="imageSrc" *ngIf="imageSrc" style="max-height: 100px; max-width:100x">
                        </div>
```

Then I have this methods in my typescript:
`component.ts`:

```js
  // properties
  readonly photoMaxSize = 2*2**20; // 2MB
  imageSrc: string | undefined; // Used to preview image
  itemForm: FormGroup;

  // constructor
  this.itemForm = new FormGroup({
        photo:              new FormControl(undefined, [FileValidator.maxContentSize(this.photoMaxSize)]),
        name:               new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]),  
   });

  // validation
  hasError(controlName: string, errorName: string){
    return this.itemForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  }

  // create thumbnail when creating the form
   onAddImage(event: any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imageSrc = reader.result as string;
        this.itemForm.patchValue({
          fileSource: reader.result
        });
      };
    }
  }
```

And here comes my problem, this is sent to a backend and then it is returned as a JSON which contains a URL to the image, so I started creating in my form something like this to patch the values:

```js
patchFormOnEdit(id: number){
    this.itemService.getItem(id).subscribe(
      (res: Item) =>{
        
        // Patch strings
        this.itemForm.patchValue({
          name: res.name,
        });
        
        // Thumbnail:
        if (res.photo){
          console.log("Setting thumbnail to " + res.photo);
          this.imageSrc = res.photo;
          this.itemForm.patchValue({
            photo: res.photo,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

But it already crashes with the following:

```
R TypeError: control.value.files is undefined
    maxContentSize ngx-material-file-input.js:403
    Angular 9
    patchFormOnEdit XXXX.component.ts:140
    RxJS 13
    Angular 16
    RxJS 18
    patchFormOnEdit XXXX.component.ts:107
    ngOnInit .component.ts:101
    Angular 22
    RxJS 5
    Angular 22
    ItemTableComponent_td_39_Template YYYY.component.html:129
    Angular 11
    RxJS 5
```

My guess is that I can not map the URL to the kind of object that the library uses. How can I solve this?

My goal is having the same as I have created where I can remove the item or change it but using as src what is already saved in backend instead of something entered by the user at the moment of creation:
[image: image_filed]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I don't know if it is the correct way, but at least kind of works.

I was not able to make use of the `ngx-mat-file-input` to display the image I have from backend and I don't know if it is possible or if it just handles local files from the user.

So I created a select box to delete the item:

`component.ts`:

```js
  previousImageSrc: string | undefined; // Used to store previous image
  deletePreviousImage: boolean | undefined = undefined; // Delete backend image on patch
   ...
   ...
        // Patch Thumbnail:
        if (res.photo){
          this.imageSrc=res.photo;
          this.previousImageSrc=res.photo;
          this.deletePreviousImage = false;
        }
...
...
// Add image using the nxg-mat-file-input
onAddImage(event: any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imageSrc = reader.result as string;
        this.itemForm.patchValue({
          fileSource: reader.result
        });
      };
      this.deletePreviousImage = false;
    }
  }

  // When the user removes an image display again what is in backend
  onRemoveImage(){
    if(this.previousImageSrc){
      this.imageSrc = this.previousImageSrc;
      this.deletePreviousImage = false;
    }
  }
```

And then update the html to include this delete image function:

`component.html`

```html
             <!-- Photo -->
                    <div class="row-group">

                        <mat-form-field>
                            <ngx-mat-file-input #photo  formControlName="photo" placeholder="Image" (change)="onAddImage($event)"></ngx-mat-file-input>
                            <button mat-icon-button matSuffix *ngIf="!photo.empty" (click)="photo.clear($event); onRemoveImage()">
                                <mat-icon matSuffix>clear</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                            <mat-icon matSuffix  *ngIf="photo.empty">photography</mat-icon>

                            

                            <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('photo', 'maxContentSize')">
                                The total size must not exceed {{itemForm.get('photo')?.getError('maxContentSize').maxSize | byteFormat}} ({{itemForm.get('photo')?.getError('maxContentSize').actualSize
                            | byteFormat}}).
                            </mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        
                        <div *ngIf="imageSrc" style="float: left; margin: 5px">

                            <!-- Display Preview -->
                            <img [src]="imageSrc" alt='Item image' *ngIf="imageSrc" style="max-height: 100px; max-width:100x">
                           
                            <!-- deletePreviousImage -->
                            <div  *ngIf="deletePreviousImage !== undefined && photo.empty">
                                <br>
                                <mat-checkbox
                                    class="checkbox"
                                    formControlName="deletePreviousImage"
                                    id="item:edit:deletePreviousImage"
                                    >
                                    Delete image
                                </mat-checkbox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And following the example of the question this would look something like this:
[image: example_selectbox]